# Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot set style once stage has been set visible

Tags: java, javafx

I have a minor problem with JavaFX. I would like these scenes to be undecorated, but I get such a message. I know what's going on, but I have no idea how to solve it. 
Do you have an idea to solve this problem ?

Thanks

Error

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot set style once stage has been set visible
    at javafx.stage.Stage.initStyle(Stage.java:493)
    at DialogsBoxes.exitConfirmation(DialogsBoxes.java:43)
    at LaunchApplication.lambda$start$0(LaunchApplication.java:38)
```

DialogBoxes.java

When I comment out this piece of code exitStage.initStyle (StageStyle.UNDECORATED); everything is okay, but I would like the closing window to be undecorated.

```
    @FXML
    private AnchorPane exitAnchorPane;

    @FXML
    private Button confirmExit;

    @FXML
    private Button confirmReturn;

    @FXML
    void exitConfirmation(MouseEvent event) {
        exitApplication();
    }

    @FXML
    void returnConfirmation(MouseEvent event) {
        returnToApplication();
    }

        public static Stage exitStage = new Stage();


        @FXML
        public static void exitConfirmation() throws IOException{
            Parent exitRoot = new FXMLLoader().load(DialogsBoxes.class.getResource("ExitBox.fxml"));
            Scene exitScene = new Scene(exitRoot);

            exitStage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);
            //exitStage.initModality(Modality.WINDOW_MODAL);
            //exitStage.initOwner(stage);
            exitStage.setScene(exitScene);

            exitStage.show();
        }

        public void exitApplication(){
            Platform.exit();
            //System.exit(0);
        }

        public void returnToApplication(){
            exitStage.close();
        }

}
```

LaunchApplication.java(Main Controller)

```
public static Stage stage = null;

@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {

    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("LoginUI.fxml"));

    Scene scene = new Scene(root);

    stage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);

    stage.setScene(scene);

    this.stage = stage;

    stage.show();

    KeyCombination combination = new KeyCodeCombination(KeyCode.ESCAPE, KeyCodeCombination.SHIFT_ANY);
    scene.setOnKeyPressed(event -> {
        if(combination.match(event)){
            try {
                DialogsBoxes.exitConfirmation();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

}


public static void main(String[] args){

    launch(args);
}
```

Comment: Don't store the stage in a static variable and simply create and configure it each time? Either that, or track if the stage has been shown before and skip the call to `initStyle`. You might also want to consider using a [`Dialog`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/Dialog.html) or, probably better for this, an [`Alert`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/Alert.html) (extends `Dialog`).

Comment: The error message seems pretty clear to me... Solution: make sure the initialisation happens at most once and only, if the `Stage` hasn't been displayed yet...

Answer (score 0):

initWindow() must be called before showing the stage.

e.g

parentAccessAuthenticatorStage.initOwner(Main.scene.getWindow()); parentAccessAuthenticatorStage.show();